# How to create a clock in console?

Tags: prolog

I have to create something like [this](http://irinaciocan.ro/inteligenta_artificiala_2017_s2/video/ceas.mp4).

I know how to write the current time but I do not know how to update it.
My guess is that I should use the `now` predicate?

Still, I have no idea how to update the output like in the video.

I tried `write('\b')` but it didn't delete anything from the output.

Any tips are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can do something like:

```
run :-
 loop(0).

loop(X):-
 format("~w",[X]),
 sleep(1),
 flush,
 tty_clear,
 X2 is X +1,
 loop(X2).
```

This will clear the whole window, but I am not sure if `tty_clear` works on windows.

Comment: Am I doing it right? write(a), write(b), write('\b'), flush_output. Result:
ab
yes

Comment: `loop(X):-
    format("~w",[X]),
    sleep(1),
    flush,
    write('\b'),
    flush,
    X2 is X +1,
    loop(X2).`
(will go weird after 10 but you can fix that).